# How to display value after the bar using chart.js

Tags: javascript, charts, tooltip, chart.js

My chart.js

```
var ctx_1 = document.getElementById('https_http').getContext('2d');
var myChart_1 = new Chart(ctx_1, {
type: 'horizontalBar',
data: {
    labels: ['HTTPS Pages','HTTP Pages'],
    datasets: [{

        data: [ {{ $array_https_http[0] }}, {{ $array_https_http[1] }}],
        backgroundColor: [ 
            'rgb(81, 170, 120)',
            'rgb(198, 222, 208)'
        ]

    }]
},
options: {
    showAllTooltips: true,
    tooltips: {
          enabled: true,
          displayColors: false,
          yPadding: 20,
          xPadding: 30,
          caretSize: 10,
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(240, 240, 240, 1)',
          bodyFontSize: 16,
          bodyFontColor: 'rgb(50, 50, 50)',
          borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,1)',
          borderWidth: 1,
          cornerRadius: 0,
          yAlign: 'bottom',
          xAlign: 'center',
          position: 'custom',
          custom: function(tooltip) {
            if (!tooltip) return;
            // disable displaying the color box;
            tooltip.displayColors = false;
          },
          callbacks: {
            // use label callback to return the desired label
            label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
              return tooltipItem.yLabel + " : " + tooltipItem.xLabel ;
            },
            // remove title
            title: function(tooltipItem, data) {
              return;
            }
        }
    },
    responsive: false,
    legend: { display: false },
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero:true,
            },
            gridLines: {
                display: false
            },
        }],
        xAxes: [{
            ticks: {
               stepSize:100
            }
        }],
    }
}
});
```

My tooltips code

```
Chart.Tooltip.positioners.custom = function(elements, position) {
if (!elements.length)
  return false;

var em = elements[0]._model;

return {
  x: em.x-((em.x-em.base)/2),
  y: em.y+em.height/4
}
}
```

My output
[image: mychart]

My expected output
[image: expectedchart]

Is there anyone can help me how to put those value after the bar like the second picture. I just want to display the value to know even its zero. My custom tooltips was to show a different hover rather than default. All your help are appreciated and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the chartjs.datalabel plugin for achieving the need. I have created a fiddle for you -> http://jsfiddle.net/Labkrpf4/

Hope it helps!

```
var ctx_1 = document.getElementById('https_http').getContext('2d');
var myChart_1 = new Chart(ctx_1, {
  type: 'horizontalBar',
  data: {
    labels: ['HTTPS Pages', 'HTTP Pages'],
    datasets: [{

      data: [0, 430],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgb(81, 170, 120)',
        'rgb(198, 222, 208)'
      ]

    }]
  },
  options: {
    showAllTooltips: true,
    tooltips: {
      enabled: true,
      displayColors: false,
      yPadding: 20,
      xPadding: 30,
      caretSize: 10,
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(240, 240, 240, 1)',
      bodyFontSize: 16,
      bodyFontColor: 'rgb(50, 50, 50)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,1)',
      borderWidth: 1,
      cornerRadius: 0,
      yAlign: 'bottom',
      xAlign: 'center',
      position: 'custom',
      custom: function(tooltip) {
        if (!tooltip) return;
        // disable displaying the color box;
        tooltip.displayColors = false;
      },
      callbacks: {
        // use label callback to return the desired label
        label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
          return tooltipItem.yLabel + " : " + tooltipItem.xLabel;
        },
        // remove title
        title: function(tooltipItem, data) {
          return;
        }
      }
    },
    responsive: false,
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
        },
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        },
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          stepSize: 100
        }
      }],
    },
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        align: 'end',
        anchor: 'end',        
        backgroundColor: function(context) {
          return context.dataset.backgroundColor;
        },
        borderRadius: 4,
        color: 'white',
        formatter: Math.round
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You save my day.

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: Just a weird question. I have one canvas that all the output are zero and they give me a datalabels in center (not in the left) but when I have a value in data it was working fine. How can I able to fix that?

Comment: I don’t get it, if the value is zero the bar will not be drawn how the label takes the centre of a bar which is not rendered. If you see the plugin option the align property decides the position of labels which accepts start, centre or end.

Comment: I update my content. It was working well when it has a value but when its all 0 in one canvas plugins will work but it was on the middle. Thank you for everything.